# mTLS on webhooks

Tags: tls, digital-signature, mutual

I'm not understanding how does Sendgrid verify that's it's me who's sending them the HTTPS request on their webhook endpoint.

Specifically, in their [docs](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook-security-features) they show how to obtain their public key (to verify that I'm connected to sendgrid) but do not show how to upload my public key to verify my signature. I suspect that they give you some kind of client-credentials that you send them to verify your identity (after verify their signature ofcourse)?

Also, why do they generate a separate public/private key pair for each client? Why not give everyone the same public key for signature verification?

Comment: "Why not give everyone the same public key for signature verification?" -- because then it would not validate anyone. Everyone would have the same key ...

Comment: What do you mean "It will not valiadate, everyone will have the same key"? I sign with the private key and anyone with the public key can verify the signature

Comment: For example, Google does not generate a new key pair for each client

Comment: *"I'm not understanding how does Sendgrid verify that's it's me who's sending them the HTTPS request on their webhook endpoint."* - it is your Webhook endpoint, not theirs. You give them the URL where they should send the data to. Und you give them the URL when you are authenticated on their site.

Comment: Yes it's my endpoint. But the problem remain: what if a machine in the middle receives their request instead of my machine, Sendgrid needs a way to verify my signature to avoid this attack no?